# How to customize laravel passport error on login?

Tags: laravel

public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
    {

```
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {

        if ($exception instanceof ValidationException) {

            return response()->json([
                'message' => $exception -> getMessage(),
                'errors' => $exception -> validator -> errors()
            ],422);
        }
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}


protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException  $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthenticated'],401);
    }
    return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
```

the error in login request
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "The provided authorization grant (e.g., authorization code, resource owner credentials) or refresh token is invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to another client.",
    "hint": "",
    "message": "The provided authorization grant (e.g., authorization code, resource owner credentials) or refresh token is invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to another client."
}

```
login controller

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use IssueTokenTrait;

    private $client;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->client = Client::find(2);
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        return $this->issueToken($request,'password');
    }

    public function refresh(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'refresh_token' => 'required'
        ]);

        return $this->issueToken($request,'refresh_token');
    }

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        # code...
        $accessToken = Auth::user()->token();

        DB::table('oauth_refresh_tokens')
            ->where('access_token_id', $accessToken->id)
            ->update(['revoked' => true]);

        $accessToken->revoke();

        return response()->json([], 204);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific on what you are trying to achieve. There is even no question in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize the error messages like this:

```php
$messages = [
    'required' => 'The :attribute field is required.',
];

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
```

More on that: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#custom-error-messages